# Table of contents title not displayed if chapter has been customized

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have a problem with the table of contents.

When I redefine the style of the chapter, the name of the table of contents (at the top of the table) is not displayed.

If I have understand well, the style of the table of contents is defined by the style of the chapter. But it doesn't matter the style I use, it's never displayed.

Do you have any idea, what can cause that ? Is a package missing ?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \usepackage{titletoc}

    \titleformat{\chapter}[block] 
      {\begin{picture}(330,180)} {%
        \put(0,230){% 
          \makebox(0,0)[lb]{%
            \colorbox[named]{Aquamarine}{\Huge \textcolor{white}{\thechapter}} 
          }
        }
        \textcolor[named]{Aquamarine}{\sc{\put(40,235){\parbox[t]{300pt}{\huge\filright #1}}}}
      } 
      {0pt}{}
      [\end{picture}]
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-200pt}

    \begin{document}
      \tableofcontents
      \chapter{TestChapter}
      \section{TestSection}
      \chapter{Test}
    \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `numberless` key since the table of contents is a numberless chapter,  like this:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{...}{}{0pt}{...}
```